# Array column and value in sql

Tags: php, sql

my name's Tony. I am trying to find the way to change this in SQL:
1/

```
 $sql = "select..from..where column_1 = ".$val_1." and column_2 = ".$val_2." and ...and column_n = ".$val_n." ";
```

------>

```
 $sql = "select..from..where [ column,".$val." ] ";
```

with column run into 1 -> n; $val run  into 1 -> n.
2/ Example:

```
 If ($val_2 == '') -> $sql = "...where column_1 = ".$val_1." and column_3 = ".$val_3." and ... column_n = ".$val_n." ";
```

---

Can i do it ? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array and fill it with values which are not empty:

```
 $sql_where_clause = array();
 for ($i = 1; $i <= n; $i++)
 {
     $val_to_test = 'val_' . $i;
     if (!empty($$val_to_test))
         $sql_where_clause[] = "column_" . $i . " = '" . $$val_to_test . "'"; 
 }

 $sql = "select..from..where " . implode(" AND ", $sql_where_clause);
```

Comment: yeah, it's run. Thank you very much.